# Upgrading Material-2.0.0-b2 to b3

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Since I updated my material to beta3, I have noticed breaking changes. 
My stylesheet was written with deep imports by another designer, for example:

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/style/variables';
@import '~@angular/material/toolbar/toolbar';
@include toolbar-responsive-height($mat-toolbar-height-desktop);
```

Yields errors like `Undefined Variable` or `File to import not found or unreadable`

How do I fix this for material beta3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deep imports no longer work with beta3 so you will have to replace them with

`@import '~@angular/material/theming';`

Also note that beta3 now depends on Angular 4 so make sure to check the "Breaking Changes" section of the changelog

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: I did that, plus I added some custom variables to make up for 'toolbar'. Additionally, I have an MdDialog with a config -- that's been replaced. How do I update my code now?

Comment: @Moshe, check this example: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/dialog/dialog.md . Basically you pass your data as `{"data": 1234}` in your dialog.open method, then inject it on your dialog component constructor using `MD_DIALOG_DATA`.